# Error: Got unexpected extra argument (/start-reload.sh) When setting Development live reload for FastAPI docker

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

Following the documentation in [uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker#development-live-reload) I should run my image by running:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/app myimage /start-reload.sh
```

But I get:

```
Usage: uvicorn [OPTIONS] 
Try 'uvicorn --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra argument (/start-reload.sh)
```

I managed to mount a volume by using what I found here [Debug mode?](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker/issues/3) but I think it is not elegant enough and I have to run it every time I make a change (at least I dont have to build the image)

```
docker run --name ${containerName} \
--env GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--reload" \
-p 5000:5000 \
-v $(pwd)/app:/app \
${imageName}:${versionTag}
```

My Dockerfile it is just:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:latest

EXPOSE 5000

COPY ./app /app

ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

And It works as supposed.

It is possible to be able to reload as I changing my code?

Comment: Why do you need to use Docker here?  It might be (much) easier to use an actual local development setup, in Python with a virtual environment, than to try to convince an isolation system like Docker to simulate it.

Comment: It is planned to be a lot bigger application, and I want to have scalability and replication

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `--reload` to entrypoint worked for me:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload","--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```